# How to make bootstrap dropdown draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Here is my bootstrap dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I try to implement draggable on it via jQuery UI with code

```
$('.dropdown').draggable();
```

But I can only drag it only when the dropdown menus are shown and not when they are hided. Also i cannot drag on the button but only on the `<ui>` of the dropdown list.

Can some one explain me whats the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work. You have to prevent the button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".dropdown" ).draggable({
            cancel: false,
        });
});
```